# Chart.js - mixed chart types (line/bar) on time scale causing offset problems after migration to v3

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using `chart.js` in my project where I'm having a daily-ticked time scale on the X axis and two linear scales on the Y axis. On one linear scale I'm rendering an usual line chart representing a chronological trend while rendering multiple stacked bar charts on the other linear scale, representing average stats for each day. Pre-v3 versions of `chart.js` were dictating to use a general chart type `bar` for this to work, and in my case it did even on a time scale. Only workaround I had to use to was to set the bar chart data to 12:00pm to have it centered on the day while also setting the `barThickness` manually, as it will default to `0` (?) on a time scale otherwise.

[image]

Now I've recently updated to `v3.2.0` and adjusted my options and datasets according to the migration documentation. Rendering the charts I noticed that the scale ticks were offset by half a day, thus both charts being off. After some research I found out that it was due to the `offset` option for the scale being enabled as I was using a bar chart.

[image]

Manually turning off the `offset` option is to no avail either though. Besides the time scale not using up another day anymore, the ticks are still off by half a day.

[image]

Cutting out the bar chart dataset resets the ticks back to normal. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to apply the offset only to the bar charts. Does anyone have an idea how to deal with this?

I have now created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/StrikeAgainst/pen/MWJdabg) example for this.

```
    scales: {
        x: { // time scale 
            type: 'time',
            offset: false,
            time: {
                unit: 'day',
                displayFormats: {
                    day: 'iii, dd.MM'
                }
            },
            bounds: 'ticks',
            grid: {
                color: "#444",
                zeroLineColor: "#888",
                zeroLineWidth: 2
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Date'
            }
        },
        yT: { // line chart scale
            position: 'right',
            beginAtZero: false,
            grid: {
                color: "#444",
                zeroLineColor: "#888",
                zeroLineWidth: 2
            },
            ticks: {
                maxTicksLimit: 24,
                stepSize: 9000,
                callback: (duration) => String(duration / 3600) + 'h'
            }
        },
        yR: { // bar chart scale
            position: 'right',
            beginAtZero: false,
            grid: {
                color: "#444",
                zeroLineColor: "#888",
                zeroLineWidth: 2
            },
            ticks: {
                maxTicksLimit: 48,
                stepSize: 10800,
                callback: (duration) => String(duration / 3600) + 'h'
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Duration'
            },
            stacked: true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened an issue on GitHub where I was told that I also had to explicitly set the `grid.offset` option to `false`, and this fixed it for me.